# How to handle two inputs which depend on each other?

Tags: reactjs

Let's say that I have to `<select>` lists:

```
<select valueLink={this.linkState('parent')}>...</select>
<select valueLink={this.linkState('child')}>...</select>
```

Child select depends on parent select (when parent is selected then child is filled with new options and its value is set to first option by default.

The problem is that in order to "reset" child select I would have to set component state in response to state-change event, which is highly discouraged AFAIK. So how to handle this situation?

Comment: Just to clarify, you want the options of your child select to change when the value of parent changes?

Comment: yes, exactly, however it is simple to just display different options when parent changes - the problem is that I have to "reset" child value.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your issue correctly, this may help.

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/badAdviceGuy/zw1gkpy4/1/)**

By changing what options the select has we automatically reset it when we change the first select. I've also made the second select completely dependent on the first select's state.

```
<select valueLink={this.linkState('select')}>
    {this.renderOptions(Object.keys(this.selectOptions))}
</select>
<select>
    {this.renderOptions(this.selectOptions[this.state.select])}
</select>
```

let me know if I misunderstood your issue.

**Update / EDIT:**

I think I understand your issue a bit more. In this case you have a complicated relationship with your two inputs, and can't rely on the 1:1 relationship that `this.linkState()` gives you.

In this case I added a custom `onChange` method to the first select and set the value and initial value of the second selection from that. Since the second selection isn't doing anything fancy we can use `linkState` on it just fine.

**[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zw1gkpy4/2/)**

```
<select onChange={this.handleMainSelectChange}>
    {this.renderOptions(Object.keys(this.selectOptions))}
</select>
<select valueLink={this.linkState('secondSelection')}>
    {this.renderOptions(this.selectOptions[this.state.mainSelection])}
</select>
```

And the click handler

```
   handleMainSelectChange: function (event) {
    var value = event.target.value;

    this.setState({
        mainSelection: value,
        secondSelection: this.selectOptions[value][0]
    });
```

Comment: Hey, it is not exactly what I wan - component state contains only `select` value and it does not contain the second select value. I am not familiar with react best practices but it would be nice to have state with both selects values cause it would perfectly describe UI state - but maybe I am wrong?